# ATOM.io with PHP-CS-Fixer in windows

Tags: windows, php, composer

I'm a Windows user. I recently moved to ATOM.io and installed an ATOM package which uses PHP CS Fixer.

Following the installation guidelines I installed PHP CS Fixer globally with Composer and it works like this from the command line:

**php-cs-fixer [name-of-the-file]**

So, PHP-CS-Fixer was fine, but unfortunately the package that uses it wasn't working... and looking at the source I found that the package was doing something like this:

**php php-cs-fixer [name-of-the-file]**

The difference in syntax is small, but that was the problem. I edited it and it's working now.

But the question is: How can I use php-cs-fixer as an argument of PHP to make the package work without changes?

There are many reasons why I want to stay with the original package source (ex: updates)... Also I've tested a few extensions which aren't working either and I think it's a similar problem.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/pfefferle/atom-php-cs-fixer/issues/6

That issue already fixed, just input full path, for example: **C:\tools\php-cs-fixer.phar**